# Quartz scheduler job migration

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

Consider the following scenario.

Server 1: Quartz 1.x running in JDK 1.4 code

Server 2: Quartz 2.x running in JDK 1.6 code

Different set of job table for each server(but in the same schema). The instance name and 
instance id are unique to each server.

Now, I'd like to migrate jobs from server 1 to server 2. To do this I'm allowed to write code that will run either on server 1 or on server 2. The code must create a copy of existing server 1 jobs in server 2 job tables. Once they are created, existing jobs in server 1 must be deleted.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Quartz 1.8.x to Quartz 2.0 Migration Guide](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/migration-guide), especially the *Making Changes For Setups Using JDBCJobStore*:

> If you use JDBCJobStore, you will need to make several changes to the database to transform it to the new expected schema.

The migration script is provided and it is quite long. Basically you need to convert old database table schema to Quartz 2.0.

Comment: Tomasz - I have read the document before. I think you got my question wrong. I'm not trying to create new job or create new tables. I have already created new set of tables and I'm done with my code change.
Now, I'm trying the migrate jobs (that are already there) from one set of job table to another set of job table(i.e, from one server to another). Can this be done?

Comment: @AndrewAnderson: if I understand correctly you want jobs from Server 1 to be run on server 2. If you have migrated the database schema on Server 1 it is enough to copy all the records from Server 1's database to Server 2. Of course the scheduler name has to be the same so the scheduler on Server 2 picks up new tasks after restart.

Comment: Tomsaz - I can't move jobs in one go. I have to keep server 1 up for some time. Sort of step by step migration. Also, we have different scheduler names.
My concern is, if I'm trying to migrate a job to server 2 and delete the same job from server 1 (both actions must be performed from server 1), then won't I need 2 sets of quartz.properties since these servers have unique instance names which is configured using the quartz.properties file. 
Is this exercise possible?