# quartz compatibility with jdk version 1.4

Tags: quartz-scheduler, java

Did anyone know maximum version of quartz I can use when i use jdk 1.4?

I already try to search everywhere but could't find it. In [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9988893/quartz-scheduler-job-migration) :

> Server 1: Quartz 1.x running in JDK 1.4 code
>
> Server 2: Quartz 2.x running in JDK 1.6 code

But i try to use quartz

```
<groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
<artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
<version>1.8.6</version>
```

And then i know that org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory is have wrong version 49.0, should be 48.0 to use in JDK 1.4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The version that support for JDK 1.4 is quartz 1.5.2, you can get it's jar [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/quartz/quartz/1.5.2). And the dependency for maven repository is like this :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>quartz</groupId>
    <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Then use it like this (surround it with try catch):

```
Scheduler s = sf.getScheduler();
s.start();
JobDetail jd = new JobDetail("MyJobq", "Job_Group", UpdaterJob.class);
CronTrigger ct = new CronTrigger("MyTrigger", "MyTrigger_Group", "0/1 * * * * ?");
s.scheduleJob(jd, ct);
```